# flash swf crossdomain.xml accessing webhost

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, crossdomain.xml

i already uploaded my swf file on my webhost but everytime it runs, it didn't fetch the records on my database. i already tried placing my crossdomain.xml at the root folder inside the public_html. i also found out that it always access my localhost insted of my webhost (e.g. anydomain.com). i did try different approach but still no luck. i definitely need your help.

@crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>       
    <allow-access-from domain="anydomain.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: there's no reason for it to try to access a localhost unless you have set it up that way which means it's a code problem.

Comment: i try to use a debugger for my swf called "fiddler2". it displays error 502 and its host is "localhost" which is supposedly my domain. i double check all my url path and its all good. i quite desperate solving this error.

Comment: Post your Actionscript code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a browser cache problem. Try to use Firefox and install an extension called Empty Cache Button 2.7 so you can clear the cache every time you test or you could be loading the same swf forever.

Also , when calling you server side script for the database query try to pass a random parameter such this:

```
flashvars = {} 
flashvars.playlist = "playlist.xml?t=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Also open developer tools console when accessing to your site and you will be able to see/debug what is going on on the network tab

Comment: i dont think so. i've already tried it on different computers and all but still same error. it should access the webhost's database not the localhost. in my debugger, it always display that my swf are accessing the database in my localhost which means it's not connecting on my webhost's database.